# sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score in ANN regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

When I run the following code I receive

> ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method.

My code:

```
def create_network():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='mse',
                  metrics=['mae'])
    return model

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
neural_network = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_network, 
                                 epochs=100, 
                                 batch_size=10, 
                                 verbose=1)

X=feature_normalization(X)[0]


from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(neural_network, X, y, cv=4)
```

But I can't use accuracy in regression model. Any clues how can I still use `cross_val_score`  without making k-fold cross validation from scratch like here:

```
for i in range(k):
    print(f'Processing fold # {i}')
    X_test = X[i * num_val_samples: (i+1) * num_val_samples]
    y_test = y[i * num_val_samples: (i+1) * num_val_samples]

    X_train = np.concatenate([X[:i * num_val_samples],
                              X[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]],
                              axis=0)
    y_trains = np.concatenate([y[:i * num_val_samples],
                              y[(i+1)*num_val_samples:]],
                              axis=0)
    model = create_network()
    model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              epochs=num_epochs,
              batch_size=10,
              verbose=1)
    val_mse, val_mae = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
    all_scores.append(val_mae)
```

Comment: You have a regression problem, hence you should not use a `KerasClassifier` wrapper but a `KerasRegressor` one.

Comment: @desertnaut , thank you! My script started to execute! But there is one more problem  `cross_val_score` returns only mean_absolute_percentage_error regardless of what scoring method I chose on the estimator. For example if I change to `metrics=['mean_absolute_error']` `cross_val_score` will once more return mean_absolute_percentage_error. Please tell me if if it could be changed.

Comment: Comments are not a good place for such discussions. I kindly suggest you close this thread and open a new question describing in detail the new situation and issue(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross_val_score function does not recognize the metrics used in keras model and by default its None, try adding scoring='accuracy' to the cross_val_score

Comment: I've updated the code by using a wrapper but still there is a problem with accuracy because I can't use it in regression model.